# Replace all dots in paragraph with new line except that dots between numbers and after Dr., Mr., Bsc. .... etc

Tags: php, regex

Replace all dots in paragraph with new line except that dots between numbers and after Dr., Mr., Bsc. .... etc.

For Example:

Consider this Paragraph

```
My name is Ayman. I'm 31 years. I'm 1.92M. I have BSc. degree in Computer Engineering
```

I want to apply such REGEX and convert it as the following:

```
My name is Ayman.
I'm 31 years.
I'm 1.92M.   <===== note the '.' between 1 and 92 did not replace with new line
I have BSc. degree in Computer Engineering  <=== the same . after BSc did not replace with new line
```

I tried the following but this REGEX replace all dots.

```
$desc['contents']=preg_split("/(?<!\..)([\?\!\.]+)\s(?!.\.)/",$desc['contents'],-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Why regex? A simple loop would be much easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$str = "My name is Ayman. I'm 31 years. I'm 1.92M. I have BSc. degree in Computer Engineering";

$str = preg_split("/([\?\!\.]+)(?=\s+[A-Z])/",$str);

foreach($str as $new_str)
{
    echo $new_str.".<br />";
}
```

Output

```
My name is Ayman.
I'm 31 years.
I'm 1.92M.
I have BSc. degree in Computer Engineering.
```

[Demo](http://viper-7.com/7buKO5)

Comment: No it is not that simple. [Test with this input `My name is Mr. Ayman. I'm 31 years. I'm 1.92M. I have BSc. Maths degree in Computer Engineering`](https://regex101.com/r/bK6mA4/5)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for search:

```
(?:BSc|[JSMD]r|Mr?s|\d)\.(*SKIP)(*F)|(\.\h*)
```

and replace by `"$1\n"`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA7rZ7/1)

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?:BSc|[JSMD]r|Mr?s|\d)\.(*SKIP)(*F)|(\.\h*)/i', '$1\n', $str);
```

You can add more word patterns in `(?:BSc|[JSMD]r|Mr?s|\d)` that you want to ignore before DOT.

`(*SKIP)(*F)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use capturing group like this:

```
/\.\d|BSc\.|Mrs?\.|Dr\.|([.!?])/
```

And *replace* all matches of substitution `\1` with `.\n`.

Note that I think you need to ignore `.` before numbers like `.1` not after a number like `And counter is 30.`